# How to view strings from a many-to-many relationship using blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

```
TableOne

id|Topic
1 |football
2 |Rugby
3 |Cricket
4 |Tennis

TableTwo

id|name
1 |bill
2 |tom
3 |Sally

PivotTable

id|name_id|Topic_id
1 |2      |2
2 |2      |3
3 |2      |4
4 |3      |1
5 |1      |4
```

First of all from looking at the code below I have defined my authenticated user who is 'tom'. From the tables above I have the following code:

```
 $authuser = Auth::User(); //tom

 foreach ($authuser->usersubject as $chosensubjectname)
  {
      var_dump($chosensubjectname->name);
      }
```

The code above gives me the following output when I output this to my browser:

```
string(5) "Rugby"  string(7) "Cricket"  string(6) "Tennis"
```

As you can see this is not an array and so im unsure how to split these 3 sets of strings. Can anyone please tell me how to output this in blade not as a collection. I mean one topic at a time. I only want to display just one of my choosing. E.g. just 'Rugby'. (Laravel 4.2)

By the way the code below defines the many-to-many relationship between TableOne and TableTwo.

```
 public function usersubject(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('SubjectList', 'subjectlists_user', 'name_id', 'Topic_id');
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed your relations. We don't know how you defined `usersubject`

Comment: How do you want to choose just one?  What is the criteria?  Why would you want to choose Rugby over Cricket and Tennis?  If you just want to show the first one, you can just use `break;` to break out of the loop after you `var_dump()`.

Comment: Ultimately I need the user to be able to deselect what they've already chosen. I'm using the 'isset' method however I do want to check if all three are set. I don't mind which topic gets displayed I just need to display one of them at a time or if just one of them is set.

Answer (score 0):

Had to post as a reply rather than a comment.

```
$authuser->usersubject->toArray()
```

The above code will give you an array of the objects rather than a collection. But if you are loading these from a database how are you going to be unseting the variables? If you are trying to list the options a user hasn't selected. You could try.

```
DB::table('SubjectList')->whereNotIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

Comment: I've decided to use a completely different approach. Thanks for your answer though